# Rendering differences in Firefox and Chrome for elements with position:absolute

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

Apparently, elements with `position:absolute` nested in a `span` with `position:relative` render differently in Firefox and Chrome. I have two such elements in a `span` with `position:relative` that I need to overlay and the problem is that I can't overlay them in both Chrome and Firefox.

Here are images describing the issue:

**Firefox**
[image]

**Chrome**
[image]

**CSS:**

```
.csv-upload-btn{
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 0 10px 4px;
    height:20px;
    width: 54px;

    #id_uploaded_file {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:2; 
        opacity:0;
        height: 16px;
        width: 47px;
    }

    .upload-btn {
        background: url(images/btn-upload-bg.png) repeat-x 0 0;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0 5px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        color: #fff;
        width:47px;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I understand this isn't a lot to go on, but unfortunately, this is all I can legally share. Any ideas and suggestions would be appreciated. I will provide more details if/when I can get a hold of my partner

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: You can't set the width or height of an inline element. Have you tried setting `.csv-upload-btn` to `display: inline-block`?

Comment: You can when it is absolutely positioned:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/fhnku4r9

Comment: Throw some `display:block;`s in that there button.

Comment: and `.csv-upload-btn` appears to be unclosed in this post.

Comment: @cimmanon It's not absolutely positioned. Relative http://jsfiddle.net/2dRwf/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/qyaPU/ Please provide more info, because there is only enough to take it this far.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, Unfortunately, no. that would require me to share a significant amount of code, which I can't do due to legal obligations

Comment: @JasonLydon I'll try that and let you know

Comment: @JawwadZakaria consider that the thing you're seeing should be reproducible in a minimal, generic html+css. Doing so usually helps you find out what you're doing wrong while reducing, which is the most powerful way to self-discover the answer to a problem. So even if you can't, try anyway, which keeping all the content generic text.

Comment: So I managed to figure it out. I simply added a float:right and display:block to csv-upload-btn and a display:inline to .upload-btn which fixed the problem. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Set your #id_uploaded_file to top: 0, left: 0.  It is absolutely positioned but you haven't specified the position.

```
 #id_uploaded_file {
        position:absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index:2; 
        opacity:0;
        height: 16px;
        width: 47px;
    }
```

HTH.